# what's wrong with my select query in model php codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

here is my code :

```
 function getValue($id)
  {
        $this->db->select('value');
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $q = $this->db->get('ref_table');
        $data = array_shift($q->result_array());
        $result = $data['value'];
        return $result;
  }
```

when executed emerge error array conversion to string

Comment: The function itself seems correct. Can you show us how you're calling this function and what you're doing with it?

Comment: In the error message it should say a line number, what code do you have at that line number?

Comment: error in this line @GluePear :  $data = array_shift($q->result_array());

Comment: here's in controller.. I use these function in if else statement -- if($data['total'] == $this->model->getValue(0)) { $data['status'] = "unknown"; } can you help me ? @uri2x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error gives you the answer **Array conversion to string**

Try this

In model

```
 public function getValue($id)
  {
        $this->db->select('value');
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $q = $this->db->get('ref_table');
        $result = $q->result_array();
        return $result;
  }
```

In Controller

```
$data['value'] = $this->Model_name->getValue($id);
$this->load->view('my_view',$data)
```